# Facebook Graph Api access a list of a users apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to access a Facebook users applications (which they are an 'Insights Users', 'Tester', 'Developer' or 'Admin)  via the graph API?

Comment: _“It seems in the user there is an 'applications' field ”_ - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/ doesn’t mention any such field. Besides, what exactly do you mean by “the user’s applications”? The apps the are an admin/developer/tester for? Or the ones they are simply a user of?

Comment: Sorry you're right. I was looking at some outdated blog. I am after the applications they are at least an Insights Users of. If this is not possible any app that they are a admin for would be a start.

Updated question to reflect this.

Comment: Yeah, looks like that existed in API v1, but was removed after (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/user mentions a field “`/applications/developer` – List of apps of which this person is a developer”, but in later versions that doesn’t exist any more.) I don’t think this is available via API. You can only get the users with a role in an app for a specific application, and it needs the app access token – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/app/roles

Comment: That's a shame. Just noticed https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/adnetworkanalytics/ . It states if you don't pass app_ids it will default to all apps. Sadly for me the data is always empty even though I have multiple apps with Audience Network enabled.

Comment: @bencallis - did you ever find a solution?